# Mudar o fundo do HTML quando input for true

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estou fazendo um site onde terá como fundo uma foto do Heisenberg dizendo "Say My Name" com um input do tipo text no meio da tela e quando o usuario digitar Heisenberg o background irá mudar para uma foto dele dizendo You Goddam right, porém não estou conseguindo, como faço isso usando JQuery?

```js
$("#SayMyName").focusout( function(){
    var SayMyName = $("#SayMyName").val();
    if (SayMyName == "Heisenberg") {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
    }
    else {
        SayMyName = " "
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="SayMyName" name="SayMyName">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem que ser com JQuery? CSS não basta?

Comment: não, pois preciso verificar se o usuario digitou o nome corretamente

Comment: Eu sei disso, eu perguntei se a mudança no back tem que ser feita com o jquery? A verificação pode ser feita com vanilla javascript?

Comment: prefiro JQuery pois é o que estou estudando no momento

Comment: o erro se dá inicialmente pois ```url()``` é uma função que espera receber uma string com o path e ela está recebendo algo que não é uma string, o certo seria usar aspas simples ali ```"url('/myimage.jpg')"``` isso inicialmente, depois tem que conferir se o path está correto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente o path para a url da imagem está errada, caso seja o diretório corrente não precisa da / no `/myimage.jpg` ou podes usar também `./myimage.jpg`, além disso, faltam os apóstrofos dentro do url. Fora isso, o else não está fazendo nada... já que só atribui um espaço em branco pra uma variável que não é mais utilizada dentro do escopo dela.

<s>A seguir eu coloquei o seu código, só que alterando o `background-color`, afim de mostrar que a lógica em si está correta, possivelmente, precisando verificar só o path do `background-image`.</s>

A seguir eu coloquei o seu código, utilizando uma imagem qualquer...

```js
$("#SayMyName").focusout( function(){
    var SayMyName = $("#SayMyName").val();
    if (SayMyName == "Heisenberg") {
        $("body").css("background-image", "url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/05/02/21/49/laptop-336373_960_720.jpg')");
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="SayMyName" name="SayMyName">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: não está errado, ta tudo correto, mas mesmo assim não está funcionando

Comment: Você mudou a url da imagem?

Comment: Editei para funcionar com uma imagem...

Comment: @FelipeAvelar se a pessoa digitar `Heisenberg` bater enter o form recarrega. Troque `<form action="">` por `<form action="javascript:void(0);">`

Comment: @VitorCorrea, a imagem só aparece quando a pessoa clicar fora do `<input>` o evento escolhido é `focusout`.